# What => means in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I can't understand this code's syntax. Can someone help describe what it means?

```
const el = () => document.createElement('span');
const set = (el, c) => (el.style.backgroundColor = c, el);
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/bevacqua/pen/KMwQPM

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions